# with what program can i open dll files

Tags: dll

I need to open dll file I already tried programs such as dotpeek but I found out it's not supported I also tried to google for other programs but didn't find anything.
what other programs can I open it with

Comment: Try simple windows notepad

Comment: In what sense do you need to open the dll? Do you want to see what symbols are defined in it, or do you to view the raw object code?